# Assigning cell value changes its type

Tags: vba, excel

My function returns different string values.
For example: `8:15` or `7` or `B`
I assign it to a cell like this:

```
MonthDaysRange1.Cells(1, i).Value = DayValue(i, MonthNum)
```

After that, Excel changes format of the cells to Time. Cell turns into `8:15:00`. I don`t want that.
Even if I use this:

```
MonthDaysRange1.NumberFormat = "String"
```

Cell value still `8:15:00`
I only want to populate cells with text, without any changes to the format.

Comment: try this : .NumberFormat = "@"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
With MonthDaysRange1.Cells(1, i)
     .NumberFormat = "@"
     .Value = DayValue(i, MonthNum)
End With
```

test

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a string then preface it with '

```
Range("A3").Value2 = "'8:15"
```

Comment: You don't need the the ' if you use Value2

Comment: @Fratyx - Value2 does not work this way for write ; the string gets converted to a time value when its entered